# Spark Cluster Python Version

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, environment

I'm trying to run a notebook on a Spark Cluster composed by a master and two slaves.

In the master i have python 3.6.2 installed with anaconda, in slaves I have python 3.6.2 installed manually.

For each slave this is the */etc/environment*

```
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.2.0
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.6
```

But still, when I run my notebook I get this exception -

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 123, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

Could you please help me?

Edit:

These are the env variable.

```
[root@spark-worker-1 ~]# echo $SPARK_HOME
/opt/spark-2.2.0
[root@spark-worker-1 ~]# echo $PYSPARK_PYTHON
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
[root@spark-worker-1 ~]# echo $PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
python3.6

[root@spark-worker-2 ~]# echo $SPARK_HOME
/opt/spark-2.2.0
[root@spark-worker-2 ~]# echo $PYSPARK_PYTHON
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
[root@spark-worker-2 ~]# echo $PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
python3.6
```

Comment: Try to echo those environment variables as the user that owns the slave process and paste the results, please.

Comment: I will edit my post.

Comment: Did you set those environment variables before or after starting the slave process?

There is a chance that when you started it, the user did now have those variables set and therefore the process could not inherit them. In this case, try to restart the service and check.

Comment: I did set those before starting the slave. And also tried to reboot the instance without positive results.

Comment: Error is python version is different on driver and worker. Check on which driver is started and worker on which task is executed and then compare python versions. If that's not the case then check python installations available on workers and make the version you need as default in path(or in spark properties)

Comment: Dear @NachiketKat, on both workers and master there is python 3.6.2 installed. Default python is 3.6.2 and environment variables are set as required but i still get the error.

Comment: What command do you use to run your notebook? does it call a script or a function in which these environment variables might be set to a different value

Comment: I'm actually using Jupyter to run the notebook. It brokes with the instruction 
qualification_df.show()